# How can I present a UIMenu from a UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, uimenu

I want to display a menu from a tap gesture on a UIView. How can I achieve this?

```
let privacyTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.editVisibilityPressed(sender:)))
metaInfoStack.addGestureRecognizer(privacyTap)
```

...

```
@objc func editVisibilityPressed(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let view = sender.view
    let menu = UIMenu()
        ....
}
```

Comment: Can you not make the view a `UIButton` instead?

Comment: You can not programmatically present a UIMenu. You can use `UIButton` or a `UITabBarItem` with a menu and the system will present the menu based on the user interactions.